# when 'add to cart' button is clicked ,it should be disabled until product is removed from the user's cart page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am doing my first project in web development. i am using php ajax and jquery. I am looking for a solution to the following problem:

When a user clicks 'add to cart' button, that (product/'add to cart' button for that product) should be disabled for that particular user until the user removes the product from his cart page. i.e user should not be able to add the same product again and again into the cart.

this is my javascript file,"init.js"

```
('.add_to_cart').on('click dblclick',adding);
//$("body").on(".add_to_cart","click",adding);
function adding(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
     var prodid =$(this).attr("id");
    var that = $(this);
    that.off("click dblclick"); 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "addcart.php",
        data:{prodid:prodid}
    }).done(function(msg) {
         alert(msg);
    }).always(function() {
        that.off("click dblclick",adding); 
    })

};
```

this is php file,"addcart.php"

```
<?php
session_start();
/*if(isset($_SESSION['islogged'])){

  if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
 echo "Please log in to add books to your cart";
}
*/

require_once 'connect.inc.php';
if (isset($_POST['prodid'])) {
  if (!empty($_POST['prodid'])) {

    if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
      echo "Please log in to add books to your cart";
    } else {
      $product_id = $_POST['prodid'];
      $username = $_SESSION['username'];
      $query = "SELECT * FROM `books1` where `id`='$product_id'";
      $query_run = mysqli_query($link, $query);
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
        $productname = $row['name'];
        $productid = $row['id'];
        $productauthor = $row['author'];
        $productpublication = $row['publication'];
        $productcategory = $row['category'];
        $productsubcategory = $row['sub_category'];
        $productborrowalprice = $row['borrowal price'];
        $productimage = $row['image'];
        $query1 = "INSERT into `cart`(`user_name`,`p_id`,`p_name`,`p_author`,`p_publication`,`p_category`,`p_subcategory`,`p_borrowalprice`,`p_image`,`qty`)VALUES('$username',$productid,'$productname','$productauthor','$productpublication','$productcategory','$productsubcategory','$productborrowalprice','$productimage',0)";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query1);
        if ($result) {
          echo 'successful';
        } else {
          die(mysqli_error($link));
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: your code remove the click and double-click handlers so that the customer can no longer click "add to cart". Doesn't that do what you want?

Comment: yeah!! it does the job,but when i refresh the page,i am able to add the same product again to the cart... i want to disable the button of that product until he removes product from cart.i have no idea of solving this issue... do help..

Comment: is your html inside a `.php` page?

Comment: yeah!!! could you just tell me how to solve my problm...

Comment: Show the HTML that is rendering the buttons (maybe just a couple of buttons)

Comment: Kindly refer this BettleJuice https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_Tu00toB5WraP_Rw7srXUjV9lnvHpb9-JyedhiZtA6c

Comment: you need to have a separate query that lists the items in the cart already. so you want to check that array and disable the button if the product id is already in the cart.

Comment: thankyou jidexl21,this would actually work... thankyou

Answer (score 0):

you use btn.loading and btn.reset. save your btn as a variable to avoid clashes when the scope changes.

```
$('.add_to_cart').on('click dblclick',adding);
//$("body").on(".add_to_cart","click",adding);
function adding(e) {
 var cur = $(this).button("loading");
    e.preventDefault();
     var prodid =$(this).attr("id");
    var that = $(this);
    that.off("click dblclick"); 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "addcart.php",
        data:{prodid:prodid}
    }).done(function(msg) {
         alert(msg);
    }).always(function() {
        that.off("click dblclick",adding); 
      cur.reset()

    })

};
```

Comment: thankyou for your answer,sir.. i actually want that loading text until the user removes the product from his cart(i.e) even if the user refreshes his page,he should have the text "loading" for the products he added to cart ,until he removes from his cart.